# How to remove class-objects-bar from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated to Android Studio 2.3 and there is now a bar between the editor window and the tabs bar that displays the objects within a file
[but most of the time it's just empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLpuT.png).

There is no context menu when I right-click on the new bar and I cannot seem to find any mention of it in the android studio guide. There doesn't even seem to be an acknowledgment of it in their own [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVLKl.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feather is called Breadcrumbs and was introduced in [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-2)

> **Breadcrumbs**: Until now breadcrumbs were only available in HTML and XML code. Now breadcrumbs work for Java, too, where instead of tags they let you navigate through classes, lambda expressions and methods.

it's a pretty useful feather but if you don't like it you can disable it by going to Settings/Editor/General/Appearance/Show breadcrumbs.
[image]

Comment: Much obliged. I did see that ticked in the settings, but thought it was something else. Just curious, what are your thoughts on the breadcrumbs bar now being enabled by default for java files? I don't doubt that for massive projects with giant files it is helpful, but it does takes up valuable space on my laptop screen.

Comment: Thanks, with this stupid AS I feel like using Microsoft. They think they always know better when developers want.

Comment: I think Breadcrumbs is very useful in large files, and particlarry useful when using nested classes, and it's not uncommon in a medium android project to have fragments with inner classes and this feature helps a lot in knowing exactly where am I.